# PHP installed, but show warning with phpenv

Tags: php, centos

I installed PHP with phpenv, and the result is below,

```
[Info]: Loaded apc Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded pyrus Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded xdebug Plugin.
(...)
[XDebug]: Compiling in /tmp/php-build/source/xdebug-2.2.5
[XDebug]: Installing XDebug configuration in /home/vagrant/.phpenv/versions/5.5.14/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
[XDebug]: Cleaning up.
[Info]: Enabling Opcache...
[Info]: Done
[Info]: The Log File is not empty, but the Build did not fail. Maybe just warnings got logged. You can review the log in /tmp/php-build.5.5.14.20140712183504.log
[Success]: Built 5.5.14 successfully.
```

It seems that PHP 5.5.14 installed successfully, but the process puts out warning log,

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Makefile.rej
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c: In function ‘php_openssl_setup_crypto’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:330: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:338: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:343: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:347: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:351: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:355: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:363: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:368: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/zlib/zlib.c:1023: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c: In function ‘zif_curl_getinfo’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c:2456: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_curl_slist’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to struct curl_slist * for this info
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c:2566: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_getinfo_err_curl_slist’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_getinfo expects a pointer to struct curl_slist * for this info
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c: In function ‘_php_curl_setopt’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c:1867: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_long’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a long argument for this option
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/interface.c:2002: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_progress_cb’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_progress_callback argument for this option
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/streams.c: In function ‘php_curl_stream_opener’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/curl/streams.c:312: warning: call to ‘_curl_easy_setopt_err_progress_cb’ declared with attribute warning: curl_easy_setopt expects a curl_progress_callback argument for this option
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.c: In function ‘apprentice_load’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.c:781: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_php_stream_opendir’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/main/php_streams.h:348: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/filters/mbfilter_iso2022jp_mobile.c:51: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.c: In function ‘php_mcrypt_filter_create’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt_filter.c:210: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘mcrypt_module_open’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/include/mutils/mcrypt.h:38: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/soap/soap.c: In function ‘serialize_response_call’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/soap/soap.c:3902: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘php_escape_html_entities’ from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/standard/html.h:57: note: expected ‘size_t *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/soap/soap.c:3927: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘php_escape_html_entities’ from incompatible pointer type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/standard/html.h:57: note: expected ‘size_t *’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/xsl/xsltprocessor.c: In function ‘zif_xsl_xsltprocessor_transform_to_doc’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/ext/xsl/xsltprocessor.c:669: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/Zend/zend_opcode.c: In function ‘zend_clear_trait_method_name’:
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/Zend/zend_opcode.c:273: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_efree’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/php-build/source/5.5.14/Zend/zend_alloc.h:60: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.
```

Does PHP 5.5.14 is installed correctly?
How do I resolve these warnings?

OS: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource I find useful for determining whether individual build messages are "usual". I have selected the appropriate page for your version of PHP

http://gcov.php.net/viewer.php?version=PHP_5_5&func=compile_results

Hope this proves useful